# How to update stock quantity in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-update

In my windows form application have two tables which are stock and GRN. When I insert GRN data to database, stock table should also update according to received quantity of GRN.I did this query to update it.But if I need to edit the received quantity of GRN.How can I update stock table.I did this for update stock, when create GRN

```
 public void insertquantity(int quantity,string ISBN_No)
    {
        DynamicConnection constok = new DynamicConnection();
        constok.mysqlconnection();
        constok.sqlquery("UPDATE TBL_Stock SET Quantity = IsNULL(Quantity,0) + @quantity where ISBN_No = @ISBN_No");
        constok.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@quantity", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        constok.cmd.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = quantity;
        constok.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ISBN_No", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        constok.cmd.Parameters["@ISBN_No"].Value = ISBN_No;
        constok.nonquery();
    }
```

I need to do something like this

```
 public void editquantity(int quantity, string ISBN_No)
    {
        DynamicConnection constok = new DynamicConnection();
        constok.mysqlconnection();
        constok.sqlquery("UPDATE TBL_Stock  SET Quantity = IsNULL(s.Quantity,0) - (received quntity in GRN table) + (new quntity to be saved to GRN table) where ISBN_No = @ISBN_No and GRN_No=@GRN_No");
        constok.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@quantity", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        constok.cmd.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = quantity;
        constok.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ISBN_No", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
        constok.cmd.Parameters["@ISBN_No"].Value = ISBN_No;
        constok.nonquery();
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is `DynamicConnection` ? What isn't working with what you're currently doing?

Comment: That class consist with connection open,sqlcommand,nonquery.,etc methods

Comment: OK, but you've not shown the definition. You've not shown what `sqlquery(...)` does, **you've not told us what the problem you're experiencing is**. For all we know the code inside `sqlquery(...)` simply does nothing and never sets the query value on the underlying object.